# Is it possible to grant a user permission to deploy Preview Channels only with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to create an IAM role that allows users to only deploy a web app to preview channels, but not to the "Release" channel? Are there any preconfigured roles for this scenario or could custom roles be created?